# Increment a number between 2 values and also process the limit of the range

Tags: javascript, for-loop, range, increment

How can I easily increment a number between 2 values (e.g. 0 and 10) by a given step (e.g. 3) and process also the limits of the range ? All numbers could be integers or floats. I was thinking of using a for-loop with an increment of 3, but then I will not have the value 10 :

```js
for(i=0; i<=10; i=i+3){
  // Do something with i
}
```

Data that shall be processed inside the loop: 0, 3, 6, 9, 10

Comment: I think that the easiest way would be to output the upper limit after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could limit the upper bound with `Math.min`.

```js
const
    step = 2.7;

for (let i = 0, l = Math.ceil(10 / step); i <= l; i++) {
    const value = Math.min(i * step, 10);
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine, thx

```js
const lower_limit = 1;
const upper_limit = 12;
const step = 3;

var range = upper_limit - lower_limit;

for (let i=0, l=Math.ceil(range/step); i<=l; i++) {
    const value = lower_limit + Math.min(i*step, range);
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const start = 0;
const limit = 10;
const step = 3;
let i = start;

for (i = start; i <= limit; i+=step) {
    console.log(i);
}

if ( i !== limit) {
    console.log(limit);
}
```

Comment: If limit is 9 your code will print two 9. Your output will be 0,3,6,9,9

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28014853)

Answer (score 0):

```
function example(){
    let start = 0;
    let end = 13;
    let step = 3;
    let arr = [];
    for(i=start; i<=end; i=i+step){
        arr.push(i);
    }
    if(arr.indexOf(end) === -1)
        arr.push(end);

    console.log(arr.join());
}
example();
```

Try to execute this function in browser snippets